# Shortcodes not processing inside post content

Tags: php, filters, shortcode

I have shortcodes inside my post_content in a custom post type wordpress. But when I `echo` the post content, all the shortcodes are not getting applied.

What I've tried so far:

```
$post = get_post(post_id, OBJECT);
echo apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
```

I've also applied the `do_shortcode()` function but that also doesn't process the shortcodes. I've already applied most of the solutions present on this platform but no luck. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: The way you apply `the_content` filter looks correct. Do the shortcodes display natively in a default theme? Just to make sure that the shortcodes work as expected and are properly registered?

Comment: Thanks @NightHawk. But how do I check that. I'm currently using a child theme.

Comment: The easiest way would be to download and activate a default WordPress theme-- I always keep one around to test whether my themes are an issue. Then visit the same page after you activated the default theme to see if the shortcodes display. There is one caveat, which is that it's possible that the shortcodes were defined in the theme, in which case that's not a good test-- still worth a try. Can you tell me the shortcodes that don't work?

Comment: Actually I'm using a custom template for a page where I'm echoing out custom post content so don't think the method you suggested would work because th custom template lies in the child themes. 
Shortcodes are basically related to `Learndash ` plugin.

Comment: You can copy that shortcode to any post or page, and it should also work, even if it throws an error that there is missing data... this will at least tell you whether the shortcode is firing or whether it just prints out the brackets.

Comment: It didn't work their either.

Comment: I'm inclined to believe that the shortcodes are not properly registered then. In other words, the issue is not that they are not processing, the issue is that they don't exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111984/discussion-between-sohaib-ahmad-and-nighthawk).